# Force exerted on a circular coil due to a current being induced in that circular coil

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-induction

Suppose the switch is closed on a circuit with a DC supply connected to a circular coil of wire. Another identical coil (that is not connected to any power supply) is next to it and my understanding is that it experiences a repulsive force, relative to the original coil, due to the current being induced in this coil acting to oppose the magnetic field that caused it. Therefore, we have a current through this 2nd coil and a magnetic field acting through it that it induced due to Faraday's Law.

Will there be a force acting away from the centre of this 2nd coil (perpendicular to the induced magnetic field) using Fleming's Left Hand Rule? As we have current flowing and a magnetic field through the coil, but the magnetic field was caused by the current flowing through that coil.

Comment: Are you asking about the magnetic force of the second coil on the first one or on itself?

Comment: On itself, due to the current flowing through it